# Is forwarding a port(s) a security risk to all computers on the network or just one?

Tags: server, ports, risk

I know forwarding ports can add some security risk, but if I forward a port to a computer, say running linux, would it add a security risk to all computers on my network or just the one?

Comment: All computers. See [Attack Pivoting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploit_(computer_security)#Pivoting).

Answer (score 2):

All computers.

Say whatever service is running on that port (e.g., web server, database server, etc) is found to be vulnerable to an attack that allows the attacker to execute any code of his choosing on the server (typically we call this a remote code execution attack). The attacker could leverage this to then begin attacking other computers on the network.

The safest thing to do would be to segment your network. If you have one server that needs to be accessed by the outside, put it in a DMZ. The rest of your network should go behind another firewall to protect them.

Answer (score 1):

If the computer you are forwarding to is secure, then no, there isn't a risk, however if that computer gets compromised and it is inside the network, the attacker will then have access to anything that computer has access to.  It is generally best to place an additional firewall between any computers answering requests from the Internet from the rest of your internal network if you can.

If you can't and you need the service, make doubly sure to keep the system up to date and patched since it will have an exposed attack surface.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is better suited to other StackExchange sites, for instance [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/), just a short answer:

Yes.

If you are exposing a port you have a risk of the computer being compromised. An infiltrator could exploit a weakness in the protocol to take over the exposed computer and start attacking other computers on the same network.